# getting all the object related to the object added when using ModelMultipleChoiceField

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to create a sign up form where the user can specify many categories and languages from a list, but when I signup up choosing one or two objects from the list, I found that the new user is stored with all the objects. It is like I had checked all the objects.

**forms.py**

```
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm, ModelForm): 
    categories=forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.all(),
                     widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(), required=True)
    languages = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Language.objects.all(), 
                     widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(), required=True) 

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email','categories', 'languages']
```

**models.py**

```
class User(AbstractUser, models.Model):
    password1 = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField('Category')
    languages = models.ManyToManyField('Language')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Language(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**views.py**

```
class SignUp(CreateView):
    form_class = SignUpForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('index')
    template_name = 'registration/signup.html'
```

Comment: What makes you think the user is being stored with all the objects?

Comment: i checked the user in the admin page and it is stored with all categories and languages objects

Comment: No it isn't, the admin page shows you all the choices which are available for you to select.